# Continuous Deployment in Github actions asp.net core solution

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, github-actions

I am trying to understand github actions I have a project with three projects I would like to build but the main solution file appears to build the entire solution.

As you see my projects are contained within the master solution The projects I want it to build are

I only want to build
models
dal
web
web api
and the bl projects

[image]

```
name: .NET Core

on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master ]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Setup .NET Core
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1
      with:
        dotnet-version: 3.1.301
    - name: Install dependencies
      run: dotnet restore
    - name: Build
      run: dotnet build --configuration Release --no-restore
    - name: Test
```

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/M64Vj.png]

But I am getting the following error.

> /opt/hostedtoolcache/dncs/3.1.301/x64/sdk/3.1.301/NuGet.targets(282,5):
> error MSB3202: The project file
> "/home/runner/work/MISSystemWeb/MISSystem.Tests/MISSystem.Tests/MISSystem.Tests.csproj"
> was not found.
> [/home/runner/work/MISSystemWeb/MISSystemWeb/MISSystem.Web.sln]
> /opt/hostedtoolcache/dncs/3.1.301/x64/sdk/3.1.301/NuGet.targets(282,5):
> error MSB3202: The project file
> "/home/runner/work/MISSystemWeb/MISSystemCalls.Api/MISSystemCalls.Api/MarineTrafficAPi.csproj"
> was not found.
> [/home/runner/work/MISSystemWeb/MISSystemWeb/MISSystem.Web.sln]
> /opt/hostedtoolcache/dncs/3.1.301/x64/sdk/3.1.301/NuGet.targets(282,5):
> error MSB3202: The project file
> "/home/runner/work/MISSystemWeb/MISSystemPostCodeLookup.Api/PostCodeLookupApi/PostCodeLookupApi.csproj"
> was not found.
> [/home/runner/work/MISSystemWeb/MISSystemWeb/MISSystem.Web.sln]
> /opt/hostedtoolcache/dncs/3.1.301/x64/sdk/3.1.301/NuGet.targets(282,5):
> error MSB3202: The project file
> "/home/runner/work/MISSystemWeb/MISSystemPluginManager.MNG/MISSystemPluginManager.MNG/MISSystemPluginManager.MNG.csproj"
> was not found.
> [/home/runner/work/MISSystemWeb/MISSystemWeb/MISSystem.Web.sln]
> /opt/hostedtoolcache/dncs/3.1.301/x64/sdk/3.1.301/NuGet.targets(282,5):
> error MSB3202: The project file
> "/home/runner/work/MISSystem.Mobile/MISSystem.Mobile/MISSystem.Mobile/MISSystem.Mobile.Android/MISSystem.Mobile.Android.csproj"
> was not found.
> [/home/runner/work/MISSystemWeb/MISSystemWeb/MISSystem.Web.sln]
> /opt/hostedtoolcache/dncs/3.1.301/x64/sdk/3.1.301/NuGet.targets(282,5):
> error MSB3202: The project file
> "/home/runner/work/MISSystem.Mobile/MISSystem.Mobile/MISSystem.Mobile/MISSystem.Mobile/MISSystem.Mobile.csproj"
> was not found.
> [/home/runner/work/MISSystemWeb/MISSystemWeb/MISSystem.Web.sln]
> /opt/hostedtoolcache/dncs/3.1.301/x64/sdk/3.1.301/NuGet.targets(282,5):
> error MSB3202: The project file
> "/home/runner/work/MISSystemWeb/MISSystem.ConsoleTest/MISSystem.ConsoleTest/MISSystem.Imports.csproj"
> was not found.
> [/home/runner/work/MISSystemWeb/MISSystemWeb/MISSystem.Web.sln]
> /opt/hostedtoolcache/dncs/3.1.301/x64/sdk/3.1.301/NuGet.targets(282,5):
> error MSB3202: The project file
> "/home/runner/work/MISSystemWeb/MISSystem.BL/MISSystem.BL/MISSystem.BL.csproj"
> was not found.
> [/home/runner/work/MISSystemWeb/MISSystemWeb/MISSystem.Web.sln]
> ##[error]Process completed with exit code 1.

Comment: Duplicate the solution file and then remove all unnecessary projects from one of them. You can use the new solution file for your workflow on GitHub Actions.

Comment: So u cant target a solution file that seems a limitation then to me

Comment: My project depends on the other assebmlies @LexLi